# How to update specific value without updating a whole value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
+-----+------------------+
|  id |      name        |
+-----+------------------+
|  1  | John;Black;Mike  |
+-----+------------------+
|  2  | White;Mike;John  |
+-----+------------------+
|  3  | Jacob;Mike       |
+-----+------------------+
|  4  | Will;Mason;Mike  |
+-----+------------------+
```

as result of

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%Mike%';
```

Is there any query on how to update specific name `Mike` to `Michael` without updating a whole value. like `John;Black;Mike` to `John,Black,Michael` in all rows automatically.

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should not be storing lists as strings in a single column.

Answer (score 2):

You could use replace

```
 update people 

 set name = replace( name, 'Mike', 'Michael')
 where  name LIKE '%Mike%';
```

***anyway you should avoid storing comma separated  value  .. you should think to a proper normalized  table for this data ..***